# Create additional wifi credentials on headless Pi 0

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w, wpa-supplicant

I have been accessing this Pi over SSH on a wifi per the initial install via burning a raspbian image to an SD card.  I tried unsuccessfully to add another wifi network by editing the wpa_supplicant.conf as follows:

```
network={
    ssid="OriginalWifi"
    psk="passwordSchool"
}

network={
    ssid="NewWifi"
    psk="passwordHome"
}
```

Should this work?  Or do I have to burn the SD card again with the updated wifi creds in wpa_supplicant.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an id to each network and possibly a priority if there is a chance to have both detectable at the same time:

```
network={
    ssid="OriginalWifi"
    psk="passwordSchool"
    id="school"
}

network={
    ssid="NewWifi"
    psk="passwordHome"
    id="home"
}
```

You can add a `priority=` line in each network block {} with a number after the '='.  The **HIGHER** the number the more priority it has (i.e. a priority of 2 network will be selected over priority of 1).  This only applies if both / multiple networks defined in you file are detected at the same time. e.g.:

```
network={
    ssid="NewWifi"
    psk="passwordHome"
    id="home"
    priority=2
}
```

Comment: There is NO "need to add an id to each network", although you can do so if you wish.

Comment: @Milliways - That's the only way I got it to work...